# ¿Cómo configurar VisualStudio para que sea compatible con OneDrive al ejecutar pruebas con phpunit?

Tags: visual-studio, phpunit

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto PHP Laravel en una carpeta de OneDrive para empresas, para aprovechar las ventajas de OneDrive, como por ejemplo que se respalde automáticamente; sin embargo, no puedo controlar el nombre de la carpeta de OneDrive, ya que viene determinado por defecto por la cuenta de Microsoft y en mi caso es la carpeta C:\BFC\OneDrive - BFC\aplicaciones\sacbe. El hecho de que existan espacios en la cadena de la ruta (...\OneDrive - BFC...) provoca problemas de compatibilidad de muchas maneras y me parece increíble que los expertos de Microsoft no lo sepan.
El problema que tengo ahorita es que al intentar correr pruebas con phpunit, mi editor de texto Visual Studio (que también es de Microsoft) me manda el siguiente error:

```
> c:/BFC/OneDrive\ : El término 'c:/BFC/OneDrive\' no se reconoce como
> nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de  script o programa
> ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si
> incluyó una ruta de acceso,  compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e
> inténtelo de nuevo. En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
> + c:/BFC/OneDrive\ -\ BFC/aplicaciones/sacbe/vendor/bin/phpunit.bat c:/ ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:/BFC/OneDrive\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Obviamente se está quejando del nombre de la ruta que no debiera tener espacios. Imagino que debe ser posible especificar la ruta correctamente como una cadena de texto con comillas así: "C:\BFC\OneDrive - BFC\aplicaciones\sacbe", y supongo que debería hacerse dentro de la configuración de Visual Studio, pero no sé dónde.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceré mucho.

Comment: visual studio o visual studio code? y no sera una configuracion de phpunit?

Comment: @gbianchi, si, es Visual Studio Code (no sabía que había otro) y si, quizás se pueda arreglar en phpunit, pero tampoco sé dónde insertar esa configuración. ¿Me ayudas?

Comment: Vs code no es una ide. Es un editor de texto con capacidades de ide basados en los plug in que agregues. O sea, no es que microsoft no sepa. Basicamente no le interesa pq los que se encargan de eso son quienes hacen los plugins.entoncea tu pregunta seria para quien hizo el plugin